# Railties crash on heroku, works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails server works runs fine locally. When deploying to Heroku, it crashes on startup mysteriously - I get reference to a syntax error but it is the end of a file. First it was the product_comments controller. I commented that controller & its route out, and now its the charge_customer_job. Line 73, last line of the file.. it makes me think something is failing before it starts up.

Local development works fine - I have no issue.

```
2020-08-23T21:40:19.946969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/merchants.json?page=1" host=htm-app.herokuapp.com request_id=eb590416-76eb-41f0-874b-c2ad614fafa4 fwd="66.85.224.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http2020-08-23T21:40:49.703219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting2020-08-23T21:40:55.125586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: 

Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664229+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664240+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.4.3 application starting in production
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664241+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664241+00:00 app[web.1]: CarrierWave
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664242+00:00 app[web.1]: CW INSTALLED
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664525+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': /app/app/jobs/charge_customer_job.rb:73: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664535+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664545+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664547+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664553+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664555+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664558+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664560+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664563+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664573+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664577+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664578+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664578+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664581+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664584+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'2020-08-23T21:41:04.664587+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664589+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664592+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'2020-08-23T21:41:04.664594+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664597+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664599+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664602+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664605+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664607+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'2020-08-23T21:41:04.664610+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664612+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664615+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664618+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664620+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664623+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:2:in `require_relative'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664626+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:2:in `block in <main>
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664629+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664631+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664658+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664659+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664659+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664660+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664663+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664688+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664688+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664692+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664696+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664701+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664703+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664705+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664708+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664710+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2020-08-23T21:41:04.664713+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'2020-08-23T21:41:04.668323+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-08-23T21:41:04.728814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-23T21:41:04.768247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I attempted to upgrade to ruby 2.6.6 and bundle update. Locally worked fine. Heroku keeps crashing.

How do I even begin to debug this? If it works on my machine fine.

Comment: This sounds like a class loading issue. In development.rb, set `config.eager_load = true`, and run locally. This should allow you to debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you dbugger, feel free to add this as suggested answer